# PHP utilizando $_GET

Tags: php, get

estou analisando um exemplo de codigo (TPage.class.php, do livro PHP orientado a ojetos, [Link Classe](https://github.com/flaviomicheletti/code-books/blob/master/pablo_php_oop/cap5/app.widgets/TPage.class.php)), o qual trabalha em função dos parametros passado na URL,

```
if ($_GET)//Verifica se foi passado algo junto com a URL
    //page1.php?method=listar
    //page1.php?class=Clientes&method=listar
    {
        $class = isset($_GET['class']) ? $_GET['class'] : NULL;
        //Vefirifica se foi passado uma Classe //POO
        $method = isset($_GET['method']) ? $_GET['method'] : NULL;
        //Vefirifica se foi passado um Método //Estruturado
        if ($class)
        {
            $object = $class == get_class($this) ? $this : new $class;
            if (method_exists($object, $method))
            {
                call_user_func(array($object, $method), $_GET);
            }
        }
        else if (function_exists($method))
        {
            call_user_func($method, $_GET);
        }
    }
```

Bem, estou com dificuldades para entender o que esta acontecendo dentro do if e else if, se alguem puder explicar ficaria agradecido.

Classe que utilizará a de cima:

```
<?php
include_once '../app.widgets/TElement.class.php';
include_once '../app.widgets/TPage.class.php';

class mundo{
    function helloWorld($param){
        echo 'Hello ' . $param['nome'] . '<br />';
    }
}

$pagina = new TPage();
$pagina->show();
```

?>

[Pasta com todas as Classes utilitarias(Github)](https://github.com/flaviomicheletti/code-books/tree/master/pablo_php_oop/cap5/app.widgets)

Comment: vendo os exemplos no livro, e de codigo (Github) a linha: $object = $class == get_class($this) ? $this : new $class; se faz inutil bastando:  $object = new $class; (fiz o teste de ambas as formas e obtive o mesmo resultado) se alguem discordar, compartilhe seu ponte de vista

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vou tentar explicar:

> if ($_GET)

**Supostamente**, verifica se foi passado algo junto com a URL. Esse teste é desnecessário pois $_GET é um array superglobal e acredito que esteja sempre presente, independente de [variables_order](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) conter o indicador **G** ou não <sup>necessita confirmação</sup>

Portanto é uma condição desnecessária<sup>1</sup>. O menos errado, mas ainda assim desnecessário dadas as outras condições, seria:

```
if( count( $_GET ) > 0 ) {}
```

<sup>1. Se confirmada a influência de variables_order</sup>

> $class = isset($_GET['class']) ? $_GET['class'] : NULL;

É a menor segurança possível de se fazer quando se está trabalhando com *querystrings*: Verificar se um determinado índice (**class**) foi informado na URL e está presente no $_GET:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?class=something
```

É usado um operador [ternário](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) para se criar a variável. Esse operador funciona do seguinte modo:

```
$variable = ( test ? if_true : if_false );
```

No caso, se o parâmetro GET foi passado pela URL, ele estará presente no superglobal e este será o valor da variável **$class**. Se não estiver presente -OU- for nulo (característica de [isset()](http://www.php.net/isset)), mantém-se o **NULL**.

O mesmo vale para **$method**, porém este se refere ao método da classe que será invocado.

> if ($class)

Verifica se a variável acima foi criada. Esse teste foi feito de forma errada pois apenas testa se a variável foi criada. Independente do resultado do teste no ternário a variável será criada, seja com o valor esperado ou com **NULL**.

Além disso, se apóia no *cast* burro do PHP. Se você aprender a programar assim, quando e se você evoluir na linguagem poderá potencialmente ter sérios problemas para depurar problemas sutis nos seus códigos.

Um bom exemplo disso foi [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44362/buscar-no-banco-de-dados-e-comparar/44986).

Por isso, **sempre** se deve delinear exatamente o que se está testando. Nesse caso, usando a função [is_null()](http://www.php.net/is_null) ou comparação tipada:

```
if( ! is_null( $class ) ) {}
```

Ou

```
if( $class !== NULL ) {}
```

> $object = $class == get_class($this) ? $this : new $class;

Outro ternário sendo usado para se definir qual o objeto da classe será usado.

A função [get_class()](http://www.php.net/get_class) retorna o nome da classe do objeto passado. Caso o argumento vindo de $_GET e armazenado em **$class** seja igual ao nome da classe atual onde esse fragmento de código se encontra, a pseudo-variável **$this** será usada, indicando que o método desejado (**$method**) será buscado e invocado dentro dela mesma ou, caso exista, numa superclasse da qual essa estenda.

Caso contrário o valor recebido será instanciado como se fosse uma classe diferente.

De novo, ERRADO! O autor do código assume que o argumento vindo por $_GET é uma classe existente e localizável no/pelo sistema.

Por causa do segundo `if` mal-formulado e dada a ausência de um meio de se sair do fluxo dos outros `if`, o `elseif` não será executado pois a variável **$class** sempre vai existir, anulando a possibilidade desse argumento ser considerado como função.

O menos errado, a essa altura do código, seria usar [class_exists()](http://www.php.net/class_exists) para verificar se é uma classe válida. Se não for, o teste falharia e o `elseif` funcionaria.

> if (method_exists($object, $method)) {}

O parâmetro sendo considerado uma classe, isso verifica se o método vindo por $_GET (**$method**) existe na classe, seja a própria ou a diferente, instanciada.

> call_user_func(array($object, $method), $_GET);

Se existir invoca, passando o array $_GET como argumento. Mais uma vez, ERRADO! Porque $_GET é um superglobal ele não precisa ser injetado em lugar nenhum.

O menos errado nesse caso, talvez, seria criar um novo array, cópia de $_GET e remover dele as entradas **class** e **method**, pois dificilmente esses valores poderiam ser necessários no método invocado.

> else if (function_exists($method))

Se as condições tivessem sido definidas corretamente e esse `elseif` pudesse ser executado, seria invocada uma função conhecida pelo sistema.

A título de curiosidade, a lista de funções que poderiam ser invocadas, nativas ou definidas pelo programador, podem ser obtidas através de [get_defined_functions()](http://php.net/get_defined_functions).

A diferença entre [call_user_func()](http://php.net/call_user_func) e [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) é que na primeira múltiplos argumentos são passados em uma lista infinita:

```
call_user_func( 'funcao', $param1, $param2 /** ... */ );
```

E a segunda recebe um array com N argumentos:

```
call_user_func( 'funcao', array( $params ) );
```

Porém, como foi passado $_GET e antes de ser um superglobal ele é um array, não tem diferença de uso entre as duas.

Num código bem escrito, [call_user_func()](http://php.net/call_user_func) é até aceito para criação de *aliases* de ´funções/métodos. Mas é tão complicado atingir certo grau de flexibilidade que quase sempre a outra versão é mais preferível.

Espero que ajude e, assumindo que tudo o que foi dito no seu post seja verdade, sugiro (opinião estritamente pessoal) que interrompa a leitura e procure outro material didático para que você aprenda do jeito certo desde o início.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, (muito bem explicada), uma observação minha é que a linha: $object = $class == get_class($this) ? $this : new $class; se faz inutil bastando: $object = new $class; (fiz o teste de ambas as formas e obtive o mesmo resultado)

Comment: Ele faz uma verificação se classe passado pelo parâmetro `GET` é igual a classe existente. Caso for, retorna ela mesmo, caso não for ela cria um novo objeto com a classe passada pela url da string *$class*

Comment: Esse tipo de afirmação só é possível de ser confirmada se soubéssemos o restante do código. Pelo que se tem podemos apenas afirmar que esse fragmento está dentro de uma classe, mas não podemos dizer qual e nem onde (método).

Comment: Olá @Bruno Augusto, o link para esta classe na integra esta na descrição da minha pergunta, a classe que estará utilizando a classe produto do meu questionamento estarei postando no final da minha pegunta.

Comment: Ok... Talvez eu tenha passado batido pelo link. u.u' Sim, de fato é uma condição desnecessária, mas eu me sentiria mais confortável conhecendo todo o restante, digo, onde, quando e como é suado **TPage** e **TElement** porque, numa primeirada olhada, acho que **$this** ao invés de **$class** faria muito mais sentido, já que um é filho do outro e **$this** não faz distinção entre classes e superclasses.

Comment: Ok, coloquei o link para a pasta no Github com as classes utilizadas.

Comment: Praticamente destrinchou o código todo XD