# Buscar no banco de dados e comparar

Tags: php

Tenho um código simples cujo objetivo é obter o valor de um campo e efetuar uma comparação, caso o valor seja zero, faz uma coisa, caso contrário, faz outra.

Entretanto eu devo estar errando em alguma coisa, pois não está funcionando como esperado.

Essa foi minha tentativa:

```
<?

$teste=$produto['fold'];

if($teste==0) {

?>

---

<?

} else {

?>

<a href="<?= $produto['fold']; ?>">Link</a>

<?

}

?>
```

Com este código ele entra tanto no `if` quanto no `else`. Onde está meu erro?

Comment: Algum erro em particular, ou algo que posso ajudar a descobrir o problema? $produto['fold'] possui qual valor?

Comment: Ele possui ou um link ou 0,entretanto o codigo funciona,so que ele entra tanto no if quanto no else,e não entendo o porque

Comment: Tem certeza disso @RodolfoOliveira, o problema, com certeza, não é o código estar passando no `if` e no `else` de um mesmo `statement`, por que assim que ele entra no `if`, não tem motivo para ir pro `else` e se entra no `else` foi porque não satisfez a condição imposta... Existe um looping por fora desse `if`?

Comment: Acabei de copiar e rodar aqui este trecho de código e não está com o problema que tu relatou, até porque é impossível entrar no `if` e no `else` ao mesmo tempo. Nos mostre o que tu tem ao redor deste código.

Comment: Para começar, você tem certeza que o PHP está interpretando seu código? Como você está testando?

Comment: Editado. Agora o tópico faz sentido e pode ser reaberto.

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira tente entender qual é o problema realmente. Acrescente mais informações do seu código na pergunta.

Comment: Não removi a última frase apenas para não violar a intenção do OP, mas é um teste lógico. Sim, sim, não, não, logo se entra no `If`, não pode estar entrando no `else` também.

Comment: Como assim faz sentido, @BrunoAugusto? O que ele diz que está ocorrendo é impossível! Acho que o Bacco está intuindo o problema real, o código não está sendo interpretado e por isso tanto o `---` quanto o link estão sendo impressos. Talvez seja simplesmente o caso de não usar shorttags. Ou de fato acessar o servidor se o acesso estiver sendo feito por file:///. Só que o autor precisa esclarecer o que está fazendo antes de podermos reabrir. Porque para mim continua não estando claro.

Comment: Bom, eu compreendi a questão, isolei o problema e elaborei uma resposta explicativa. Estou apenas aguardando a reabertura do tópico apenas.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Ok, estou reabrindo, poste sua resposta.

Comment: @RodolfoOliveira esse problema surge mesmo quando usas tags de PHP _completas_? ou seja `<?php` para abrir e `?>` para fechar?

Comment: Puxa... Quase que eu perco a chance por não ter visto o tópico sendo reaberto. Obrigado pelo voto de confiança.

Answer (score 2):

O problema é com o *cast* burro e intrometido do PHP.

Segundo [o manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) (tradução livre):

> Se você comparar um número com uma string ou a comparação consistir de strings numéricas, então cada string será convertida para um número e a comparação ocorrerá numericamente. […] Essa conversão não se aplica quando a comparação é feita com os operadores === ou !== uma vez que isso caracteriza comparação por valor e por tipo.

Dito isso, no seu teste:

```
if( $teste == 0 )
```

O lado esquerdo primeiramente está sendo interpretado como a variável que ele representa.

O lado direito, por ser um número "sugere" ao interpretador que a comparação deve ser numérica e com isso a string que a variável representa, passa, internamente, a ser um número também.

É como se estivesse sendo feito isso:

```
if( (int) $teste == 0 )
```

E como uma string não pode ser um número (óbvio) o resultado da conversão passa a ser zero e o resto é lógica.

Para resolver esse tipo de problema sutil e de difícil depuração use comparação tipada como diz o manual:

```
if( $teste === 0 )
```

E o link passará a ser criado.

À parte disso, deixo como sugestão que quando você estiver gerando HTML com PHP prefira utilizar a [sintaxe alternativa](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) das estruturas de controle pois fica MUITO mais fácil de compreender o abre-e-fecha de tags:

```
<?php if( $produto['fold'] === 0 ) : ?>

---

<?php else : ?>

<a href="<?= $produto['fold']; ?>">Link</a>

<?php endif; ?>
```